# sql server connection in play framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, playframework

How we can connect to Microsoft SQL Server in play framework.

I am able to connect MYSql.

I have done following config in application.conf file :

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=test"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password="test01"
```

I have also try with copy sqljdbc4.jar in my Project -> libexec folder.

Comment: Enable the TCP\IP protocoll and the port 1433 in the SQL Server Configuration Tool.

Comment: TCP/IP and port 1433 is already eanabled

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: 2016-09-06 08:46:24,995 [ERROR] from application in netty-event-loop-4 - 

! @71aigaim1 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
I am getting  Following error. I have paste few line as not able to paste all the line :
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
 at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)

Comment: 2016-09-06 08:46:24,995 [ERROR] from application in netty-event-loop-4 - 

! @71aigaim1 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
 
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
 at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)

Comment: whats your play version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to `application.config`

```
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Comment: I have added. But still not able to connect.

Comment: Thanks Tony. After adding db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1" my problem is resolved. I have also made following change. So final code will be as follow :

Comment: db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"

db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/test"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password="test01"